# Why is my string not printing in a function?

Tags: c++, string

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int lengthOfLastWord(string s) {
    int i,j,n=0;
    for(i=0;s[i]!=0;i++){
        n++;
    }
    string s1;
    for(i=n,j=0;s[i]!=' ';i--,j++){
        s1[j]=s[i];
    }
    cout<<s1;
};

int main(){
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    lengthOfLastWord(s);
}
```

What is the problem with the string `s1`? If `s1` is in the `for` loop, `s1` prints successfully.

Comment: You should change `};` to `}`.

Comment: I have changed it but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, your `lengthOfLastWord()` function doesn't return anything so have its return type be `void`:

```cpp
void lengthOfLastWord(string const& s) {
    //                       ^^^^^^ Preferably use const reference here to avoid making unnecessary copies at each invocation to 'lengthOfLastWord()'
    /* ... */
}
```

Now, the real problem is that you never initialized `s1` before accessing it with `s1[j]` which leads to *Undefined Behavior*.

So, to fix your problem, just replace this line:

```cpp
string s1;
```

with this:

```cpp
string s1(n, '\0');
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/KGP9o395b)

---

Alternatively, you can use [`std::string::push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back):

```cpp
// ...
string s1;
for(i = n; s[i] != ' '; i--)
    s1.push_back(s[i]);
cout << s1;
```

[<kbd>Demo using `std::string::push_back`</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/s3bYqT8hf)